# Custom color of draw polygon on leaflet map

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, polygon, leaflet.draw

I am drawing polygon on leaflet map

```
 this.polygonDrawer = new L.Draw.Polygon(this.map);
```

How can i customize color of this polygon? Like i want red color polygon should draw so where i can give this color option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setOptions function.

```
this.polygonDrawer = new L.Draw.Polygon(this.map, {shapeOptions: {color: '#f00'}});

//or

this.polygonDrawer.setOptions({shapeOptions: {color: '#f00'}});
```

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-polyline-setoptions

PS: leaflet geoman is a very nice and up-to-date leaflet draw alternativ library